# Last window position for an app

Tags: applications, pantheon

I'm using Telegram and whenever I open it from the dock the window appears at its last position plus (or minus) a certain vertical offset, shifting the window slightly towards the top of the screen. Repeatedly opening and closing it moves it all the way to the top.

Is the position of the window stored somewhere by the OS like `gsettings` or is this managed by the app itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a [way](https://elementary.io/de/docs/code/reference#saving-window-state) for an elementary app developer to store the last window state together with the window position. For telegram though I don't know how they handle their last known window position.

Although I am not so deep into gnome development I can only guess that the window position storage has to actively implement for each app itself and can't be mangage via a general gsettings command. Well, at least I am not aware of any schema for elementary OS that will do that.

However, you might want to create an isssue on the telegrams [github repository](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues), maybe they are a bit more of help here :-)